# Accessing values within a hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

The server is receiving the following JSON object.  The action also logs the nature of the object

```
Update: {"update_id":589695627,"message":{"message_id":190,"from":{"id":3241,first_name":"Bob","username":"Bobby B","language_code":"en"},"date":1592897101,"text":"/activate NjElMV8yMTkuMTkuNDU="}}
Rails.logger.info update.is_a? Hash
json = update.to_json
Rails.logger.info json.is_a? String
```

The logger returns true to both `is_a` queries.
The resulting json string is identical to the received statement save the `Update`  prefix.

How can one extract say `message.from.username` immediately from the hash (as it seems as overload to run a json handling loop as well)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Hash.html#method-i-dig):

```
update = {"update_id":589695627,"message":{"message_id":190,"from":{"id":3241,"first_name":"Bob","username":"Bobby B","language_code":"en"},"date":1592897101,"text":"/activate NjElMV8yMTkuMTkuNDU="}}
update.dig(:message, :from, :username) # "Bobby B"
```

Comment: `dig` is seldom referenced. Quite useful!